# How to create TextInput animation with React native reanimated?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

I'm currently learning React native and trying to create animated textinput field which will expand on focus. Currently I am doing this with the help of useState and css, but I need to use React native reanimated here.

[image: Initial state of buttons]

**Initial state of buttons**

[image]

**Required State of button on focus in message input field**

**Component**

```
const inputRef = useRef<TextInput>();
const [ focused, setFocused ] = useState(false);

 const handleBlurInput = () => {
    console.log('e')
    inputRef.current?.blur();
    setFocused(false);
  }

  const handleFocusInput = () => {
    inputRef.current?.focus();
    setFocused(true);
  }

const Footer = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.footer}>
        {focused ? (
          <IconView
            name="ChevronRightLight"
            onPress={handleBlurInput}
            style={styles.iconView}
          />
        ) : (
            <>
              <Button text="Button1" onPress={onButton1} buttonStyle={styles.button} />
              <Button text="Button2" onPress={onButton2} buttonStyle={styles.button} />
            </>
          )
        }
        <View style={styles.messageContainer}>
            <TextInputField
              ref={inputRef}
              style={[styles.messageInput, focused && styles.fullMessageInput]}
              placeholder="Message..."
              onPressIn={handleFocusInput}
              onFocus={handleFocusInput}
              onBlur={handleBlurInput}
              autoFocus={focused}
              placeholderTextColor='white'
            />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

**Styles**

```
footer: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      bottom: 0,
    },
    button: {
      marginRight: 10,
      paddingVertical: 8,
      paddingHorizontal: 8,
    },
    messageContainer: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    messageInput: {
      minWidth: 134,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: 'grey',
      paddingLeft: 11,
      color: 'white',
      fontWeight: '500',
      fontSize: 14,
      lineHeight:16,
    },
    fullMessageInput: {
      borderWidth: 1,
      minWidth: 295,
      marginRight: 60,
      height: 50,
      borderColor: 'grey',
      paddingLeft:11,
      color: 'white',
      fontWeight: '500',
      fontSize: 14,
      lineHeight: 16,
    },
```